# how to avoid Permission denied while installing package for Python without sudo

Tags: python, centos, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to install the `tesseract` wrapper for python as user `mike` so that I can `import tesseract`. I'm following the guide here https://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/wiki/HowToCompilePythonTesseractForCentos

However, when I execute `python setup.py install`

I get the error below:

```
    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-7351.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

I do have sudo access but here is the problem: When I login as `root` the default python version is 2.6, however, when I login as `mike` the default python version is `2.7` (this is the one I want). So if I do `sudo python setup.py install` then the installation for `tesseract` is taking place on `2.6` rather than on `2.7`.

What can I do in this scenario? Should I change permissions on the `site-packages` folder? I'm a bit out of options...

Comment: This Solution might be useful
http://stackoverflow.com/a/39618607/2958795

Answer (score 58):

try `python setup.py install --user`

This will install the package on **/home/your_user/.local/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages/** instead of **/usr/local/lib/** where you don't have permissions (unless you use sudo).

Comment: that got me over the bump but not fully there yet. now I get this error `error: could not create 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg': Permission denied`

Comment: probably because you've already build package as root. You need to `chown` buuild dir to yourself. Or remove it and compile again.

Comment: @Will it installs a module from source code in userspace (setup.py is provided by module authors)

Comment: works for me .. it intalled all packages in /home/user/.local/ .. great !! thanks

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can type this line as normal user:

```
whereis python
```

Assume the result is "/usr/bin/python", then:

```
sudo /usr/bin/python setup.py install
```

Comment: `python2.7` isn't found as `sudo`

Comment: is "python2.7" found as normal user? What about try "whereis python" to find 2.7 version