# cannot use yum on CentOS 6.5 (permission denied)

Tags: permissions, centos, yum

I installed Python 2.7 on CentOS 6.5, but I made the mystake to delete the previous python.
So after I installer Python 2.7, each time I want to use Yum, I got this error message:

> sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/yum: Permission denied

Please any help would be really needed

Comment: How did you install python 2.7? What does `ls -l /usr/bin/yum` say?

Comment: to install python 2.7 I followed http://bicofino.io/blog/2014/01/16/installing-python-2-dot-7-6-on-centos-6-dot-5/ 
"ls -l /usr/bin/yum" returns "-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 801 17 déc. 2013 /usr/bin/yum"

Comment: What about `ls -l /usr/{local/,}bin/python`? Also at this point you should likely not be compiling python 2.7 yourself to install it you should be using the SCL collections that RH/CentOS now provide for python2.7 instead. If you undo the `$PATH` modifications from that URL does the problem go away?

Comment: Perhaps this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22551461/how-to-avoid-permission-denied-while-installing-package-for-python-without-sudo